# How do I create a Javascript function call list that waits for the previous function to finish before calling the next?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently building a signboard system that displays timetable information in a consistent format for various locations.

The idea is that each location has its own lightweight page with a small amount of variables that define the location specific parameters and then call the appropriate functions, in order, from a single external .js file.

My page is working fine with functions explicitly chained together, like so:

```
function one (){        
    //do the thing
    two();      
}

function two (){        
    //do the next thing
    three();        
}

function three (){      
    //do the last thing
}
```

What I am trying to do is separate the functions so that I can call them from a list in each individual page which will let me substitute different versions of certain functions as required in the different locations. Something like this:

```
function callList(){     
  one();
  //wait for one to finish  
  two();
  //wait for two to finish 
  three();
}
```

I have spent a lot of time reading about asynchronous functions, callbacks, promises etc. but the solutions that have been offered still seem to deal more with chaining functions together explicitly and passing a single variable as proof the function has finished, such as this (well written) example:

https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-await/

Part of my difficulty in figuring out the right solution is that my functions are quite varied in their purpose. Many of my functions don't produce variables at all and the ones that do (with the exception of a single ajax call) produce large sets of global parameters that don't need to be explicitly passed to the next function. Most, in fact, focus on rendering and manipulating svg and text in various ways, and due to the nature of the data displayed many rely heavily on loops.

As with most javascript problems I encounter I am sure that it is merely a gap in my understanding, but I feel like I am just reading the same articles over and over again and getting nowhere. I really need someone more knowledgeable to give me a nudge in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: It matter what your functions are and what they return. If they are not asynchronous you don't need to worry, they'll run in order. But if they *are* asynchronous, you need them to return a promise or take a callback and so we need to know more about their behavior. If your functions can return Promises, async/await is a very convenient way to make this work.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Ok, so I must be misunderstanding what constitutes an async function. I only have one function (my ajax call) that is explicitly defined that way. So despite heavy looping, the other functions should still be synchronous?

Comment: Yes, javascript is basically single threaded, so loops and regular function calls all happen in order. Things like network requests and timers are async so they need special handling.

Comment: @MarkMeyer that's the nudge I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are first-class citizens in Javascript, so you can just throw them into an array and then loop through and call them.

```
var functionsToCall = [
    one,
    two,
    three
];

// Call them (use your looping method of choice)
for (var i = 0; i < functionsToCall.Length; i++) {
    functionsToCall[i]();
}
```

If your functions are synchronous and are not returning anything that you need, that's basically all you need.  If your functions are async, then you might need something more like `await functionsToCall[i]();` or a setup using promises/callbacks instead.

If you need callbacks to tell you when a function has completed, you can use a small state manager/function to handle that (or you can use async/awaits if your environment will support them - they're cleaner to write!  :) ).

Something like...

```
// A sample async function - you pass the callback to it.
function one(callback) {
    // Do some async work, like AJAX...

    // Let the callback know when I'm finished (whether I have a value to return or not.
    callback();
}

// Simple state management - wrap these up with nicer code and handle errors and whatnot.
var funcIndex = 0;
function callNext() {
    if (funcIndex < functionsToCall.Length) {
        functionsToCall[funcIndex](callNext);
        funcIndex += 1;
    }
}

// To start things off:
function callAllFunctions() {
    funcIndex = 0;
    callNext();
}
```

If you need to have more granular control over the function calling, you can put custom objects into the array instead of just the functions themselves and change the behavior based on that.

For example:

```
var functionsToCall = [
    { func: one, isAsync: true },
    { func: two, isAsync: false }
];
```

Anyway, just some possibilities.  It will really depend on exactly what you need for your particular situation!

Answer (score 0):

use await
or

use promises

or

you need function1 execution complete handler will execute next one